# How does Windows link specific files to specific thumbnails in the thumbnail cache?

Tags: windows, operating-system, filesystems, thumbnails, ntfs

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_thumbnail_cache#Purpose):

> Thumbnail caching was introduced in Windows 2000; wherein the thumbnails were stored in the image file's [alternate data stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_(ADS)) if the operating system was installed on a drive with the NTFS file system.

Here, it's clear that Windows *used* to associate thumbnail information directly with a file using its alternate data stream (on an NTFS file system). However, since Windows Vista:

> ...thumbnail previews are stored in a centralized location on the system... The cache is stored at `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` as a number of files with the label `thumbcache_xxx.db` (numbered by size)

However, I have yet to find anywhere that explains *how* Windows associates individual thumbnails in the cache with specific files on the file system.

Does Windows associate the thumbnail image with the checksum of the file? It seems unlikely/nonoptimal because Windows would have to compute the checksum of every item in a folder (when accessed) if it wanted to properly display the correct thumbnails.

Does Windows use something lower level like the [NTFS file ID of the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/ns-fileapi-by_handle_file_information#remarks)? But then how would it work on other file systems like FAT which don't assign fixed file IDs?

I have yet to find any good answers so I would really appreciate any help I could get!